# Scan multiple dirs from array

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I have the next code but i need scan multiple dir on array.

```
    public static function scanFiles($directory, $recursive = true, $listDirs = false, $listFiles = true, $exclude = '') {
    $arrayItems = array();
    $skipByExclude = false;
    $handle = opendir($directory);
    if ($handle) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            preg_match("/(^(([\.]){1,2})$|(\.(svn|git|md))|(Thumbs\.db|\.DS_STORE|\.html))$/iu", $file, $skip);
            if($exclude){
                preg_match($exclude, $file, $skipByExclude);
            }
            if (!$skip && !$skipByExclude) {
                if (is_dir($directory. DS . $file)) {
                    if($recursive) {
                        $arrayItems = array_merge($arrayItems, self::scanFiles($directory. DS . $file, $recursive, $listDirs, $listFiles, $exclude));
                    }
                    if($listDirs){
                        $file = $directory . DS . $file;
                        $arrayItems[] = $file;
                    }
                } else {
                    if($listFiles){
                        $file = $directory . DS . $file;
                        $arrayItems[] = $file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $arrayItems;
}
```

Your use is: scanFiles('path/to/folder')
But I need the path to be an array, example: scanFiles(array('path/to/folder1', 'path/to/folder2')).

Some one help...?
Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the function like this, just adding foreach with the code block that you have for scanning directory

```
public static function scanFiles($directories, $recursive = true, $listDirs = false, $listFiles = true, $exclude = '') {
    $arrayItems = array();
    $skipByExclude = false;
    foreach($directories as $directory) {
        $handle = opendir($directory);
        if ($handle) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                preg_match("/(^(([\.]){1,2})$|(\.(svn|git|md))|(Thumbs\.db|\.DS_STORE|\.html))$/iu", $file, $skip);
                if ($exclude){
                    preg_match($exclude, $file, $skipByExclude);
                }
                if (!$skip && !$skipByExclude) {
                    if (is_dir($directory. DS . $file)) {
                        if ($recursive) {
                            $arrayItems = array_merge($arrayItems, self::scanFiles($directory. DS . $file, $recursive, $listDirs, $listFiles, $exclude));
                        }
                        if ($listDirs) {
                            $file = $directory . DS . $file;
                            $arrayItems[] = $file;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($listFiles) {
                            $file = $directory . DS . $file;
                            $arrayItems[] = $file;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
    return $arrayItems;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vahan, thanks for you reply.
How could I do it with the glob() function...?
I need something like Scandir::scanFiles2(array('path/*/folder', 'another/*/folder'))